# ¿Por qué variables implícitas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

¿Por que Python usa variables implícitas?. Por ejemplo:

```
monedas = ("peso", "dolar", "libra", "yen", "cacao")
for moneda in monedas:
    print(moneda)
```

es lo mismo si uso:

```
monedas = ("peso", "dolar", "libra", "yen", "cacao")
for quesos in monedas:
    print(quesos)
```

En ambos casos obtengo el mismo resultado, pero ¿Por qué a Python le da lo mismo `moneda` que `quesos` ?

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por *variable implícita*? Tú eres quién le ha dado nombre a esas variables, no python. En particular, python se caracteriza por ser **explícito** en todo lo que hace, demasiado explícito en comparación con otros lenguajes orientados a objetos.

Answer (score 4):

Tal y como comenta ChemaCortes no queda muy claro a que te refieres con "variables implícitas". Tu mismo, de forma explicita y transparente, le estas dando el nombre que quieres a la variable. Esta variable va a almacenar los elementos del iterable al ser recorrido por el `for`. En este caso la declaras en el mismo `for` y puede ser cualquier identificador válido para una variable Python, es decir cualquier cosa que cumpla con:

- Empieze por una letra (a - z, A - B) o underscore (`_`)
- El resto de caracteres deben ser letras, numeros o `_`
- No sea una palabra reservada (`for`, `in`, `def`, etc)

> ¿Por qué a Python le da lo mismo `moneda` que `quesos` ?

Porque Python no analiza la semántica de las variables, no se pone a evaluar si un elemento de una lista llamada `monedas` es una `moneda` y no conjunto  de `quesos`. Esto pertenece al lenguaje natural, conceptos abstractos que los humanos asociamos a las palabras. El interprete solo se preocupa que el identificador de la variable sea valido en cuanto a la sintaxis del lenguaje (que no sea `1moneda`, por ejemplo), no analiza su corrección semántica, gramatical u ortográfica en cuanto al lenguaje natural que usa el programador para nombrar sus variables/clases/métodos, etc. Esto es lo mismo para cualquier lenguaje, un ejemplo similar en C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main(void){
    std::list<std::string> monedas = {"peso", "dolar", "libra", "yen", "cacao"};

    for(std::string queso : monedas) {
        std::cout << queso << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Al compilador no le parece mal que la lista `monedas` contenga `quesos`... Solo se preocupa de que sea un identificador válido y de que el tipo de la variable sea correcto.

Enlazando con lo anterior, lo que si puede ser "implicito" en Python es el tipo de `moneda`/`queso`. A diferencia de C++ donde se tiene que saber en tiempo de compilación que la lista y la variable usada en el `for` son del tipo `std::string` (por lo que tengo que especificarlo de forma explícita), esto no pasa en Python.

En Python esto no es necesario porque es un lenguaje de ***tipado dinámico***, la variable es de un tipo u otro de acorde al valor que almacena en tiempo de ejecución, cambiando de tipo cuando sea necesario. Esto tiene sus ventajas (còdigo más simple, flexibilidad, mas adaptabilidad a entradas no conocidas a priori, etc) y sus desventajas (mas lento, por ejemplo) como todo. Es muy común que los lenguajes interpretados y conocidos como lenguajes de "scripting" tengan tipado dinámico, podemos ver este comportamiento con algo como:

```
>>> lista = ['hola', 2.4, 14, True, None, sum]
>>> for elemento in lista:
        print(f'{elemento} >>> {type(elemento)}')


hola >>> <class 'str'>
2.4 >>> <class 'float'>
14 >>> <class 'int'>
True >>> <class 'bool'>
None >>> <class 'NoneType'>
<built-in function sum> >>> <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

> Recordar que una variable simplificando no es mas que un nombre que hace referencia a una dirección de memoria donde se guarda un objeto. Es una construcción para permitir a los ''humanos'' recordar y hacer referencia a esas localizaciones de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

`moneda` o `quesos` es el nombre que le pones a la variable que almacena cada uno de los elementos de `monedas`.

Puede llamarse de cualquier manera siempre que sea un identificador válido

```
monedas = ("peso", "dolar", "libra", "yen", "cacao")
for elemento in monedas:
    print(elemento)
```

Comment: A todos, gracias, me ha quedado muy claro el punto, a diferencia de ustedes estoy hecho entre lecturas y stack over flow, tengo la necesidad de programar, pero no soy programador, lo que para ustedes es obvio, para mi es una caja negra. No tengo el mejor lenguaje y reconozco que muchas veces me cuesta espresar pero al fin he resuleto mi dilema con sus explicaciones... gracias